# Normalize ISO 8601 datetime to any time zone with support of non-standard time zone abbreviations

Tags: perl, datetime, timezone, iso8601

Having time in **ISO 8601** format *(e.g.* `2019-09-17T16:15:20Z`*)*, how can I convert/normalize this time from one time zone to another time zone *(such as* `ET` *= US Eastern Time,* `CT` *= US Central Time,* `PT` *= US Pacific Time)* ?

Desired solution should accept any [time zone abbreviation](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/), standard and non-standard abbreviations.

---

*Perl subroutine*

```
sub normalizeDateTime
{
  ... # ???
}

print normalizeDateTime('2019-09-17T16:15:20Z', 'ET');
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can use `DateTime` based libraries

```
use DateTime::TimeZone;
use DateTime::Format::ISO8601;
use DateTime::TimeZone::Alias;
```

and set desired non-standard abbreviations as aliases,

```
DateTime::TimeZone::Alias->set('ET' => 'America/New_York');
DateTime::TimeZone::Alias->set('CT' => 'America/Chicago');
DateTime::TimeZone::Alias->set('PT' => 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

---

```
sub normalizeDateTime
{
  my $dt = DateTime::Format::ISO8601
             ->new()
             ->parse_datetime($_[0])
             ->set_time_zone($_ = DateTime::TimeZone->new(name => $_[1]));

  $dt . DateTime::TimeZone::offset_as_string($_->offset_for_datetime($dt))
          =~ s/^[+-]00:?00$/Z/r
          =~ s/^([+-]\d{2})(\d{2})$/$1:$2/r;
}
```

so then we can use such time zone names directly as valid time zones:

```
print normalizeDateTime('2019-09-17T16:15:20Z', 'ET');
```

> 2019-09-17T12:15:20-04:00

Answer (score 3):

**Note**  *The question and the title were changed, after this was posted and edited, to insist on requesting "*support of non-standard*" abbreviations.*

*However, use of short names is generally advised against, as the second part of this answer discussed at length already. More so, in the context of this question it is clearly a no-go as no program can know arbitrary abbreviations (and there aren't any "standards" for that, either).*

*Once a mapping to accepted names is provided then this becomes a non-issue and that had also been accounted for in the answer.  So I am leaving this answer as it is, with minor edits.*

---

Use [DateTime::Format::ISO8601](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::ISO8601) to build a `DateTime` object from your string, or in general `DateTime::Format::Strptime`.  Then use [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) as needed to work with it

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use DateTime::Format::ISO8601;
use DateTime;

my $dt_string = shift or die "Usage: $0 datetime-ISO8601\n";

my $fmt = DateTime::Format::ISO8601->new(); 
my $dt = $fmt->parse_datetime($dt_string); 
say $dt->time_zone->name; 

$dt->set_time_zone("America/Chicago"); 
say $dt->time_zone->name;
```

This uses `DateTime::set_time_zone` to convert (change) the timezone on the object.

---

The question requests that the timezone abbreviated name be used for conversions.  There is a problem with that though: abbreviated names aren't in any standard, may simply be local conventions, don't validate/work with methods from parsers ... and can even be ambiguous.

This is discussed in many places. A short summary in [DateTime::TimeZone](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::TimeZone), under the method `short_name_for_datetime`, says for "short names" (abbreviations such as those requested)

> It is **strongly** recommended that you do not rely on these names for anything other than display. These names are not official, and many of them are simply the invention of the Olson database maintainers. Moreover, these names are not unique. For example, there is an "EST" at both -0500 and +1000/+1100.

(original emphasis)

One way to still try to deal with abbreviations that are sprung on the user is with `all_names` from `DateTime::TimeZone`, and to `grep`  its output for the abbreviation of interest. For example,

```
grep { /P(?:S|D)?T/ } DateTime::TimeZone->all_names
```

returns (a list with) a sole string `PST8PDT`. This string seems valid under all methods I tried, and works correctly for setting the timezone on a `DateTime` object.  However, correct as it is, for `/E(?:S|D)?T/` this returns the list `CET EET EST EST5EDT MET WET`; not easy to use.

Clearly, this isn't systemic or reliable -- just as abbreviations aren't, to start with.

The best would be to build a local lookup of some sort, which would translate your short name to the proper name so that you'd know it's correct in your work.  Then, a stub that was added to OP (and later changed) can be filled to

```
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::ISO8601;

sub convert_time_zone_for_ISO8601
{
  my ($iso, $tz) = @_;
  # Provide a lookup/mapping that knows locally used abbreviations
  #my $tz_name = convert_local_short_name($tz); 
  my $tz_name = 'America/New_York';             # for a working example

  # Returns a DateTime object (or generate a string in a desired format) 
  return DateTime::Format::ISO8601->new
      -> parse_datetime($iso)
      -> set_time_zone($tz_name);
}

my $dt = convert_time_zone_for_ISO8601('2019-09-17T16:15:20Z', 'ET');

# Sole stringification doesn't include timezone but there are other methods
say $dt->time_zone_short_name;
say $dt->time_zone_long_name;
say $dt->strftime("%F %T %{time_zone_short_name}");
say $dt->strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z");       # RFC822-conformant
```

(See documentation notes on various printing methods.)

The chained methods building the object that is returned provide the parsing and timezone change, using an accepted timezone name.

In order for it to work with abbreviations the code clearly needs a conversion (mapping) of locally used abbreviations of interest to proper timezone names, provided by the user.

In the above snippet there's a placeholder subroutine for it, that can for example use a hash in a module with mapping spelled-out right in it, or better from a JSON file that can thus be managed by other software as well; or by querying a database table or perhaps a local service or some sort.

Comment: Note that the time zone can also be an offset (e.g. `-0500`) if you know the offset but not the political time zone. Note that doing any arithmetic on a dt created this way may invalidate the time zone. For example, `-0500` might be valid in Toronto in the winter, but Toronto uses `-0400` in the summer. Using `America/Toronto` will work year round.

Comment: Another complication is that short names are simply not unique. There are three different time zones that may use the abbreviation BST, with vastly different offsets, for example. The only solution is to keep a mapping of the time zones you care about.

Comment: @Grinnz Well, yes, I discuss that in this answer. And I suggest that the user provides a mapping ("_local lookup_" to "_translate_")

Answer (score 1):

[Time::Moment](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Moment) is great at the parsing part, but needs a little help to convert to arbitrary time zones, which I provide with a [role](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Moment::Role::TimeZone).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Moment;
use Role::Tiny ();
use DateTime::TimeZone::Olson 'olson_tz';

my $class = Role::Tiny->create_class_with_roles('Time::Moment', 'Time::Moment::Role::TimeZone');
my $mt = $class->from_string('2019-09-17T16:15:20Z');
my $tz = olson_tz 'America/New_York';
my $in_eastern = $mt->with_time_zone_offset_same_instant($tz);
```

`DateTime::TimeZone::Olson` is just an alternative to `DateTime::TimeZone` that tends to be faster for named zones; `DateTime::TimeZone` objects would also work. Determining what actual time zone to use based on your abbreviations has been covered by other answers.